# Using CSV module next() and storing the data in a dictionary to go back a row

Tags: python

I have a PYQT5 game for sports and I am using a CSV file for the data I would like to allow the user to go back and forward rows `(games)` when there is more than one game on the same day`(date)`.

At the moment I am only using the `next()` from the CSV module this works fine and in the `next_game()` method I can access the data from the row and update my labels on the UI. But when I looked for a `previous()` or a similar method I could not find one

```
def next_game():
    next_Game = next(csvreader_fix)

self.next_match.clicked.connect(lambda: next_game())
```

I would like to allow the user to have a back button and update the UI to the previous game.

I was thinking of storing the game data in a dictionary every time `next_game()` is called and using the keys to display the data for each game on the UI. I think that this will also boost performance as I will be using hashing rather than reading data from a CSV file when the user switches games and the UI is updated.

The key's will be the game number in the season so it will be easy to subtract or add 1 when a button is pressed and iterate through the dictionary.

Once the user has finished looking at that days matches the data can be discarded from the dictionary and the next days games would be placed in the dictionary every time `next_game()` is called.

Am I over complicating things and there is an easier way of achieving what I am trying to using pandas another module?

At the moment I am reading the csv file like so

```
csvreader_fix = csv.reader(fixtures)
fix = next(csvreader_fix)
```

In the 'next_game()' I access each index in the row that I need like this

```
def next_game():
    next_Game = next(csvreader_fix)
    result = next_Game[6]
    home_team = next_Game[2]
    away_team = next_Game[3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the pandas module which has more functionality.

But if you really want to use this module, you can convert the whole CSV file into a list and then access the rows in a way as you would access a list.

```
csvr = csv.reader(file)

game_data = list(csvr)
i = 0 # Or 1, if you have a header in your csv

game = game_data[i]

def next_game():
    i += 1
    next_Game = game_data[i]
   
def previous_game():
    i -= 1
    previous_Game = game_data[i]
```

Comment: Would this not be slow as each row will have about 20 index's and I only want to use a few of them. That is why I was thinking of using a dictionary?

Comment: @Conor That depends on how big your csv file is. If it is really huge (like more than a few hundred MB), it will be slow and use a lot of ram but otherwise it will be ok. I suggest you to try that and then you will see how fast it is.

Comment: Thanks for the help and its not that big but what I am concerned about is accessing the indexes in a row like so `game_data [1][2]` I have to do this a few times on each row and this would require an iteration of that row each time no?

Comment: @Conor I am not sure if I understand what you mean. No, you wouldn't have to iterate the row, you just need to know the index of what you want to access and do it as you mentioned.

Comment: I have updated the question is what you are advising me to  do the same but I can now go backward and forward rows? I have also looked into `pandas iloc()` I would like to use hashing for fast look up ideally :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can access the indexes in exactly the same way as you did in the question (eg. `next_Game = game_data[i]` `result = next_Game[6]`) You don't need the `iloc()` here, because you know the index (`i`)

Comment: Yeah sorry maybe I'm overthinking this I had the idea If I could store each row in a nested dictionary I could use hashing for each index it would be a lot faster. But still I did think I could just do it like this `next_Game = game_data[i]`

Comment: @Conor Yeah, you are overthinking IMO :) What you mentioned would probably be faster but as I understand your problem, this switching of games forwards and backwards doesn't happen so often, that's why even without hashing it would work pretty fast.